# Balancing flywheel and coupling shaft at home

Tags: mechanical-engineering, flywheels

I am rebuilding a mini soil compactor roller.

I replaced the old 8 hp Kubota diesel engine unit with a new Dongfeng unit. I want to weld the coupling shaft, which is built from 2" pipe with rubber damper at one end, to the hydraulic motor.

How can I ensure the shaft is balanced after we weld it to the flywheel? We would like to do this cheaply if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some low friction bearings you can spin it on the shaft and wait for it to come to a rest and mark the low point, do this a few times and you may see them gathering at the bottom.

Then drill out a portion of the wheel where it is heaviest and repeat.